# Linker errors when attempting to link boost::filesystem to debug MSVC11 project

Tags: c++, visual-c++, boost, linker

I'm attempting to use `boost::filesystem` in my project, but I've run into linker errors:

```
Error   14  error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found   C:\Users\Developer\Desktop\mandala3d\Debug\mandala.exe  1   1   mandala
Error   5   error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall std::bad_cast::bad_cast(char const *)" (??0bad_cast@std@@QAE@PBD@Z) already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR110D.dll)    C:\Users\Developer\Desktop\mandala3d\mandala\LIBCMT.lib(stdexcpt.obj)   mandala
Error   4   error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall std::bad_cast::bad_cast(class std::bad_cast const &)" (??0bad_cast@std@@QAE@ABV01@@Z) already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR110D.dll)  C:\Users\Developer\Desktop\mandala3d\mandala\LIBCMT.lib(stdexcpt.obj)   mandala
Error   12  error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall std::exception::exception(char const * const &)" (??0exception@std@@QAE@ABQBD@Z) already defined in LIBCMT.lib(stdexcpt.obj) C:\Users\Developer\Desktop\mandala3d\mandala\MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR110D.dll) mandala
Error   6   error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall std::exception::exception(class std::exception const &)" (??0exception@std@@QAE@ABV01@@Z) already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR110D.dll)  C:\Users\Developer\Desktop\mandala3d\mandala\LIBCMT.lib(stdexcpt.obj)   mandala
Error   7   error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall std::exception::exception(void)" (??0exception@std@@QAE@XZ) already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR110D.dll)    C:\Users\Developer\Desktop\mandala3d\mandala\LIBCMT.lib(stdexcpt.obj)   mandala
Error   8   error LNK2005: "public: virtual __thiscall std::bad_cast::~bad_cast(void)" (??1bad_cast@std@@UAE@XZ) already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR110D.dll)  C:\Users\Developer\Desktop\mandala3d\mandala\LIBCMT.lib(stdexcpt.obj)   mandala
Error   9   error LNK2005: "public: virtual __thiscall std::exception::~exception(void)" (??1exception@std@@UAE@XZ) already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR110D.dll)   C:\Users\Developer\Desktop\mandala3d\mandala\LIBCMT.lib(stdexcpt.obj)   mandala
Error   13  error LNK2005: "public: virtual char const * __thiscall std::exception::what(void)const " (?what@exception@std@@UBEPBDXZ) already defined in LIBCMT.lib(stdexcpt.obj)   C:\Users\Developer\Desktop\mandala3d\mandala\MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR110D.dll) mandala
Error   10  error LNK2005: __invalid_parameter already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR110D.dll)    C:\Users\Developer\Desktop\mandala3d\mandala\LIBCMT.lib(invarg.obj) mandala
Error   11  error LNK2005: __invoke_watson already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR110D.dll)    C:\Users\Developer\Desktop\mandala3d\mandala\LIBCMT.lib(invarg.obj) mandala
```

I am building boost with the following commands:

```
bootstrap
.\b2
```

And I am pointing to `$BOOSTDIR\stage\lib` for the library include directory and my compiler is `Visual Studio 2012 (v110)`.

I have tried directly linking the `debug` libraries that are generated in the `$BOOSTDIR\lib\*` directories but ran into other errors.  I also suspect that that is not the standard or intended way to statically link the libraries.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're mixing both C runtime library linkages and debug/release binaries.

`libcmt` is the release version of the static C runtime library, while `msvcrtd` is the debug version of the dynamic C runtime library. You have both showing up in your errors, meaning that you're trying to mix them, which you can't do.

You need to rebuild Boost to use the same version of the C runtime as your project, or rebuild your project to use the same version as Boost. However, the fact that you currently have debug and release libraries mixed is usually a sign that something else is really wrong with your settings.

If you look in your project's properties and go to C/C++ -> Code Generation, you'll see a 'Runtime Library' field. You can change this to specify how your project should link to the C runtime. /MDd will link `msvcrtd.dll`, while /MT will link `libcmt.lib`.

Comment: I changed my Runtime Library to `Multi-threaded debug (\MTd)` and now I get only one linker error: Error 3 error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_filesystem-vc110-mt-sgd-1_54.lib'.  I checked my `stage\lib` diretory and I notice that I have libboost_filesystem-vc110-mt-gd-1_54.lib, not libboost_filesystem-vc110-mt-sgd-1_54.lib.  What is the difference between these two?

Comment: Also, what are the repercussions of changing the Runtime Library?  I get the feeling that I shouldn't really be doing this.

Comment: Statically linking the run time library will force your application to use the version you built with, instead of the version found on the system. It's generally better to dynamically link. I don't know what the s in sgd means, but the name describes how the library was built; you can find a list of the symbols and their meaning in one of the Boost docs.

Comment: I checked the nomenclature and found that the `s` stands for `static`, which means that I wasn't building static libraries, but was trying to statically link them.  Rebuilding now.