# Including the Boost filesystem header

Tags: c++, boost, header, lnk2005

I have a big project.

In `N.cpp` I need to use `boost::filesystem::exists(path)` to check if the path is valid.

For that, I include `<boost/filesystem.hpp>`

I get the following error:

```
Error    2    error LNK2005: "public: enum boost::filesystem::file_type __cdecl boost::filesystem::file_status::type(void)const " (?type@file_status@filesystem@boost@@QEBA?AW4file_type@23@XZ) already defined in N.obj    D:\MProject\DA\boost_filesystem-vc100-mt-gd-1_53.lib(boost_filesystem-vc100-mt-gd-1_53.dll)    DA

Error    1    error LNK2005: "public: __cdecl boost::filesystem::path::~path(void)" (??1path@filesystem@boost@@QEAA@XZ) already defined in N.obj    D:\MProject\DAboost_filesystem-vc100-mt-gd-1_53.lib(boost_filesystem-vc100-mt-gd-1_53.dll)    DA

Error    3    error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_filesystem-vc100-mt-gd-1_53.lib'    D:\MProject\DA\LINK    DA
```

If I do not include the header file, I get:

```
Error    2    error C3861: 'exists': identifier not found    D:\MProject\DA\ThirdParty\N.cpp    108    1    DA
Error    1    error C2653: 'boost' : is not a class or namespace name    D:\MProject\DA\ThirdParty\N.cpp    108    1    DA
```

**What is the right way to use `boost::filesystem::exists` so that the whole thing would compile?**

#### N.cpp

```
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
.....
CHECK( boost::filesystem::exists(*i), std::string("file ").append(*i).append(" does not exist").c_str() );

.....
```

Comment: You´ll need to show the linker how to find the library, for `boost::filesystem`, only the includes are not enough. I think you are using Windows, right? Try a first read [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/more/getting_started/windows.html).

Comment: @wesley.mesquita The project itself knows where the library is.Boost functions are used all over the place.The problem is with multiple definitions or multiple includes of the same header, I guess. I just don't know how to solve it.

Comment: Edit your question with a snippet from your source, may help. Specially your include session.

Comment: Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19415544/linker-errors-when-attempting-to-link-boostfilesystem-to-debug-msvc11-project), seems to be a duplicated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved the problem by adding to N.cpp:

```
#ifndef BOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK
#   define BOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK
#endif 
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use `boost::filesystem` you have to include the header file (directly or indirectly via other includes).

The first three errors are linker errors. Some parts of Boost are header-only, i.e. you don't have to compile Boost when you want to use them. Unfortunately filesystem isn't one of them. That means you have to compile Boost like described [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/more/getting_started/index.html). Afterwards you have to tell your linker where it can find the binaries you just created and it should compile well (if you didn't do any other mistakes ;-) ).