# boost/filesystem.hpp not linking in osx boost installed via homebrew

Tags: c++, boost, boost-filesystem

I installed boost via

```
$ brew install boost
```

In xcode I have specified

```
/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.65.1/include
```

in my header search path and

```
/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.65.1/lib
```

in my library search path. I can successfully

```
#include <boost/variant.hpp>
```

but when I try to include boost/filesystem.hpp I get the linker error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"boost::system::system_category()"
```

The directory /usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.65.1/include/boost does include filesystem.hpp.

I tried the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21530297/cant-include-boost-filesystem-header) but it did not help with including boost/filesystem.hpp. What could be the issue?

Are there flags I should have used to install Boost?

Comment: What do you mean "it doesn't work"? Plase also state your question.

Comment: I can include boost/variant.hpp, but including boost/filesystem.hpp doesn't work. I edited the question to include the linker error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`boost::system::system_category()` is defined in `libboost_system.{so,a}`, so you need to

1. add library path `/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.65.1/lib` (or whatever that is),  and
2. link that library with `-lboost_system` linker option.

Auto-linking works on Windows only.